# excel process runing in the background after excecuting SSIS script task

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a script task in SSIS to send an email. This task calls a macro in excel, to send email using outlook. Once the mail is send the excel process still runs in the background.

```
public void Main()
        {
            string filename = "C:\\Projects\\Ashish\\Adhoc\\Data_Dashboard\\Data_Dashboard_Q4-Q1.xlsm";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename);
            xlApp.Visible = false;
            xlApp.Run("send_emails");
            xlWorkBook.Close(true);
            xlApp.Quit();


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Send the mail directly without using Excel. Convet your existing VBA code to run directly in SSIS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the below code in the macro and now excel does not run in the background after the email is send.                                             
thisworkbook.save
application.quit

Comment: You still need excel installed on your SQL Server to send emails which is completely redundant. SQL Server has its own email T-SQL API.